# Calculate the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}r^k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

How to calculate the sum of this geometric series?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}r^k, \text{ where}\; 0 \leq a \lt 1 \; \text{and}\;\; r \lt 1$$

Comment: Is there any information about the parameter $a$?

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, $0 \leq a < 1$

Comment: Well, for $a\in (0,1)$ and $|r|<1$, the sum is between $1+r+ar^2$ and $\frac1{1-r}$.

Comment: Is there a general solution for this?

Comment: It's doubtful that this has a closed-form solution in terms of anything elementary.

Comment: For $a=-1$ and $|r|<1$, we have $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k(k-1)/2}r^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n r^{2n}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n r^{2n+1}=\frac{1+r}{1+r^2}$$